# Check the render method of `App` and 21 stark frames were callpsed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am newbie and flow the tuturial the link is below https://www.michaelburrows.xyz/react-sidebar-
when I flow the steps I run npm start and get the erro

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of App.

App.js

```
navigation-component/ 
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Sidebar from "./components/Sidebar";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Services from "./pages/Services";
import Contact from "./pages/Contact";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
     <Sidebar />
      <Router>
        <Sidebar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/services" component={Services} />
          <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
    monospace;
}
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

sidebar.js

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import "./Sidebar.css";
    function Sidebar() {
        const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);
        const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);
        return (
          <nav className={sidebar ? "sidebar active" : "sidebar"}>
            <button className="hamburger" type="button" onClick={showSidebar}>
              <div></div>
            </button>
            <ul onClick={showSidebar}>
              <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
              <li><Link to="/services">Services</Link></li>
              <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        );
      }
      
      export default Sidebar;
```

Services.js

```
import React from "react";

function Services() {
  return (
    <div className="page">
      <h1>Services</h1>
      <p>This is the services page.</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Services;
```

Contact.js
import React from "react";

```
function Contact() {
  return (
    <div className="page">
      <h1>Contact</h1>
      <p>This is the contact page.</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Contact;
```

the error say 21 stark frames were callpsed

Comment: Move SideBar from Router to outer parent, any component other than route and switch should be placed inside Router.

Comment: check your home, services and contact file and see if you have exported it properly, because I can't find any error in your code

Comment: Kumar I post my services file

Comment: Piyush,Is it right to put the SideBar here? I use npm start but the it just like before,doesn't work for me .In fact I build a new project like this in a new computer .But it still don't work